# Squid proxy with ssl-bump - squid configuration error

Tags: ssl, openssl, centos, ssl-certificate, squid

i would like to install squid proxy with SSL bump, i am working on my Virtual lab and once everything is ok i will Test it on the real network.
i already created i directory for the cert and generated the cert as below:

```
#Generate Private Key
openssl genrsa -out MSY.com.private 2048  
# Create Certificate Signing Request
openssl req -new -key MSY.com.private -out MSY.com.csr
# Sign Certificate
openssl x509 -req -days 3652 -in MSY.com.csr -signkey MSY.com.private -out 
MSY.com.cert
```

then i fill the info and put the 'Common Name' something other than the domain or server_name. in addition, please find the below lines from the squid configuration file:

```
http_port 3128
#the problem is with the below line
ssl-bump cert=/etc/squid/ssl_cert/MSY.com.cert 
key=/etc/squid/ssl_cert/MSY.com.private generate-host-certificates=on 
version=1 options=NO_SSLv2,NO_SSLv3,SINGLE_DH_USE
# SSL Bump Config
ssl_bump stare all  
ssl_bump bump all
```

and its not working and if i remove the SSL bump certificate line from the configuration, the proxy works but without SSL. my questions can we eliminate SSL-bump from configuration and can i manually copy the certificate to the client/user machine and added to his/her Internet browser.

thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Also see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639) You will also need to place the self-signed certificate in the appropriate trust store.